# How to configure app.yaml file for node react project in google app engine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine, web-deployment, devops

I'm developing an application using react js and nodejs.When I run the application in local machine it works properly as a example

```
localhost:3000/AboutUs
localhost:3000
```

When I refresh the above URLs, it shows the correct web page. I deploy this application in Google App Engine and when I refresh the below page it shows that the requested URL was not found. Can any one let me know the reason for this?

```
www.mydomain.com/AboutUs
```

app.yaml code is as below

```
runtime: nodejs8
handlers:
- url: /api/.*
# secure: always
# redirect_http_response_code: 301
script: auto
- url: /
static_files: build/index.html
upload: build/index.html
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you don't have a defined handler to direct your `/AboutUs` URL. You can either add, under `handlers`:

```
- url: /AboutUs
  script: auto
```

Or add a wildcard handler at the end of the url list, for example:

```
runtime: nodejs8
handlers:
- url: /api/.*
# secure: always
# redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
- url: /
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

It's important to keep the wildcard handler `/.*` at the end, since otherwise all the URL's will fall under it, and it won't use the other url handlers.

Also you had two spaces missing in the `script`,`static_files` and `upload` tags under the url's, I don't know if it was because of the formatting when copying the `app.yaml` contents to your answer, but either way, [indentation is important](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2777534) in YAML files.

Comment: Actually I need to have this wildcard handler but it is not working

Comment: You can compare your application to [this one](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/hello-world/standard) to find any differences that might be causing the issue. Check that you have an `express` entry-point in the `app.js` file (with your application handlers defined under it). As well, check the `package.json` file, it should specify the [application startup](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#application_startup) and the dependencies you are using.

Comment: This sort of approach didn't work for me. What worked for me was the app.yaml handlers written in this question (yes, the question, it's been turned into an answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54247953/how-do-i-setup-routing-for-react-in-gae-directly-routing-to-react-router-dom-ro